# Python: marker label on the map using gmap.marker_layer option not working using hover_text

Tags: python

I am trying to label the markers i am plotting on google maps using gmap. The markers are plotted but the label (their name) are not. I using hover_text option for name to show as i hover over the marker.

Its a simple file with 3 columns --> name, lat, long.. Below is the code. Im running it on jupyter notebook

```
import gmaps
locations = df[['latitude', 'longitude']]
name = list(map(str, list(df["name"])))
fig = gmaps.figure(map_type = "TERRAIN", center = (-34, -59), zoom_level = 2)
markers = gmaps.marker_layer(locations, hover_text = name)
fig.add_layer(markers)
gmaps.configure(api_key = 'MY API KEY')
fig
```

The map plots correctly except no label.

Thanks

File:
name latitude longitude
123 -34.000000  -59.166672
124 -32.233330  -64.433327
125 -40.166672  44.133331
126 -51.216671  5.083330
127 -51.333328  4.250000

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your data is laid out, but I have encountered a similar problem which I resolved by running the following code:

```
name = [name['name'] for name in marker_locations]
```

My data is laid in the following way:

```
marker_locations = [
{'name':'Hamburg, Germany',.....},
{'name':'London, England',.....},
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add a larger snipped what you do with this new list.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) gives an example on what you want:

```
marker_layer = gmaps.marker_layer(
    locations,
    hover_text=['Atucha', 'Embalse', 'Armenia', 'Br']
```